# Texture paint colour not showing

Tags: texture-painting

[image]

Hi, I'm trying to texture paint the lips on this mesh but want to keep this original colour shown in the screenshot. However when I go into the texture paint column this colour does not show. I have attached a picture of the texture painting screen

[image: Here is a picture of the texture painting screen]

Here is a picture of the texture painting screen

Comment: have you created a new image for the Image Texture node?

Comment: Yes I added a 'image texture node' and connected to 'Principled BSDF' under shading however this changes the colour to black

Comment: could you please pack your images and share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/PNMmPVax

Comment: Done. Are you able to see it?

Comment: Yes, but you haven't given any image to your Image Texture, you need to click on New in order to create an image, otherwise you can't paint on anything

Comment: But when I click on new I'm unable to choose the orginal colour I had. I was only able to choose the original colour in the first picture because I used the eyedrop tool

Comment: Is there anyway of using the eyedrop tool when clciking on 'new'

Comment: Yes I never noticed that there were no eyedropper in this palet, but you can copy paste a color with ctrl C ctrl V, or copy the Hex reference of a color

Comment: I went to 'shading' column and added 'colour ramp' node and managed to use the eyedropper on the colour ramp node to find my original colour. However, the colours showing in 'shading' but not 'texture paint'

Comment: whoops. I was on solid view

Comment: But when I shade the lips on the mesh, I can only see the shading colour in solid view, where the colour is still black. It just shows as white shading on the viewport material preview

Comment: could you please share your current file?

Comment: I have uploaded the file https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/LEGa62Xv

Comment: I am unable to see the texture paint in viewport shading 'material preview'

Comment: plug the Image Texture directly into the Principled BSDF, don't put the ColorRamp between the Image Texture and the Principled. Look at the Shader Editor showed by @Blunder.

Comment: It worked! Thank you! But the skin tone seems to be a lot darker in solid view compared to material preview. Why is that?

Comment: Solid and Material previews don't have the same shading method, Material will use some HDRI images by default in order to simulate lights and environment, while Solid will create a more neutral shading. You can make some tweakings in the Viewport Shading on the top left of the 3D view

Answer (score 1):

Like *moonboots* assumed correctly you have no image for the texture node. You need to create one.

[image]

1. Press the "+ new" button to create an image. Give it a name
2. Select the image in the image panel on the left side so you can see the image
3. Save the image either with `Save as...` or with `Pack`

`Save` and `Save as...` will save your image in a separate file. Alternatively, you can use the `Pack`. This will pack your image into the .blend file.

**Caution!** Whatever you choose your image will **not be saved** when you save your blend file! You need to use the 'save image' (<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>) command individually. If you close Blender it will remind you when you have unsaved images. But if Blender crashes or freezes your unsaved changes of the image are lost.

Comment: After doing everything you said I'm still unable to do it. I have uploaded the file https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/LEGa62Xv

Comment: I am unable to see the texture paint in viewport shading 'material preview'

Comment: Have a look at your node setup in the shading. There is a Colorramp Node. This maps all incoming colors of the ImageTexture to skin tones. That's the reason why painting seems to have no effect. Remove the Colorramp node or mute it and you will see your texture paint.

Comment: It worked! Thank you! But the skin tone seems to be a lot darker in solid view compared to material preview. Why is that?

Comment: Great! The material preview uses an HDRI, that's a 360-degree image that contains light information. The render view uses lights in the scene. That's why materials look different. The solid view doesn't use the textures at all. You can add an HDRI to your scene, too and/or use a 3-point-lighting setup. Have a look here https://youtu.be/FzCmQpJw2I0 for details.